# Import aliases not working as expected in creat-react-app with craco

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**EDIT:** To comply with Stackoverflow guidelines and makes thing easy for all of us, I have submitted a small reproducible example that reproduces my bug:

https://github.com/shackra/stackoverflow-alias-bug

**EDIT 2:** if this is of help, I'm using `asdf` version `v0.8.0-c6145d0` to manage my `nodejs` installation:

```
~ $ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/include/node /home/jorge/.asdf/shims/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
~ $ node --version
v14.2.0
~ $ whereis yarn
yarn: /home/jorge/.asdf/shims/yarn
~ $ whereis npm
npm: /usr/bin/npm /home/jorge/.asdf/shims/npm /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1
```

---

For an existing React project I used CRA, squashed most bugs now however I cannot make my aliases to work after debugging the problem for several hours:

```
npm run build

> frontend@0.1.0 prebuild /home/jorge/code/kue/fero/dev/frontend
> nps generate-build-version

nps is executing `generate-build-version` : nps genver
nps is executing `genver` : deno run --allow-read --allow-write generate-build-version.ts

> frontend@0.1.0 build /home/jorge/code/kue/fero/dev/frontend
> nps build

nps is executing `build` : craco build
craco:  *** Cannot find ESLint loader (eslint-loader). ***
Creating an optimized production build...

● Webpack █████████████████████████ building (11%) 12/16 modules 4 active
 css-loader › postcss-loader › src/App.css

Failed to compile.

./src/App.tsx
Cannot find module: 'pages/AdminLand'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install pages/AdminLand.


The script called "build" which runs "craco build" failed with exit code 1 https://github.com/sezna/nps/blob/master/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#failed-with-exit-code
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `nps build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jorge/.npm/_logs/2020-11-29T02_52_51_308Z-debug.log
```

my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@casl/ability": "^4.1.6",
        "@casl/react": "^2.1.1",
        "@craco/craco": "^5.8.0",
        "@sentry/browser": "^5.27.6",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "antd": "^4.8.6",
        "axios": "^0.21.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "craco-antd": "^1.19.0",
        "currency.js": "^2.0.3",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "nps": "^5.10.0",
        "nps-utils": "^1.7.0",
        "print-js": "^1.5.0",
        "query-string": "^6.13.7",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-context-devtool": "^2.0.0",
        "react-cosmos": "^5.5.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "typescript": "^4.0.3",
        "ulid": "^2.3.0",
        "url-regex": "npm:url-regex-safe@^1.0.2",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "nps": "nps",
        "clean": "rm -rf build",
        "prebuild": "nps generate-build-version",
        "start": "nps start",
        "build": "nps build",
        "test": "nps test",
        "cosmos": "nps cosmos",
        "lint": "nps lint",
        "lint-fix": "nps lint.fix",
        "tsc": "nps tsc",
        "bump-patch": "nps bump-patch",
        "bump-minor": "nps bump-minor",
        "bump-major": "nps bump-major",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/classnames": "^2.2.11",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
        "craco-alias": "^2.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^6.0.1",
        "favicons-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.1.0",
        "webpackbar": "^5.0.0-3"
    }
}
```

and finally my craco.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
// ...

process.env.BROWSER = 'none'

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
   // ...
  ],
  webpack: {
    // ...  
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/'),
        modules: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/modules/'),
        pages: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages/'),
        types: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/types/'),
        utils: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils/'),
      },
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
  },
  jest: {
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      '/node_modules/(?!antd|@ant-design|rc-.+?|@babel/runtime).+(js|jsx)$',
    ],
    configure: {
      moduleNameMapper: {
        '^components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
        '^modules(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/modules$1',
        '^pages(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/pages$1',
        '^types(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/types$1',
        '^utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This is how I extend my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "pretty": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "baseUrl": "src"
    }
}
```

I provide the following for guidance, this is my project's directory layout.

```
.
├── build
│   ├── icono.svg
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── meta.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── CHANGELOG.rst
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── cosmos.config.json
├── craco.config.js
├── default.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── generate-build-version.ts
├── index.js
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package-scripts.js
├── public
│   ├── icono.svg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── meta.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
├── replace-interface-with-decimal-type.el
├── src
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── CacheBuster.tsx
│   ├── components
│   ├── cosmos.decorator.tsx
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── ability
│   │   ├── authorization
│   │   ├── invoice
│   │   ├── notification
│   │   └── resource
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── AdminLand.tsx
│   ├── react-app-env.d.ts
│   ├── react-context-devtool.d.ts
│   ├── sentry.jsx
│   ├── serviceWorker.js
│   ├── styles
│   │   └── antd
│   ├── types
│   ├── utils
│   └── vendor.d.ts
├── tsconfig.custom.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

I tried using the [babel resolver plugin](https://medium.com/bootstart/why-you-should-use-babel-resolvers-210615fc41d) without success. Any help dealing with this?

Comment: [reduce this](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). you're mixing node and deno: which is the problem? Remove all the code that has _nothing_ to do with the one that is not the problem.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Deno has nothing to do with my error, I'm just using it for scripting instead of node. I've removed some sections of code.

Comment: Still @shackra, the example is still pretty bloated and is tedious to reproduce. If you follow and make a Minimal, Reproducible Example (ie make a new project and reproduce it) chances are as well that you’ll find it. If not, it’s what everyone else will do in order to be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Johan done! I have added a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that craco.config.js format needs correction.

Change

```
 webpack: {
    resolve: { // WRONG you do not need resolve for craco.config.js
      alias: {
        things: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/things/"),
      },
```

to

```
webpack: { 
      alias: {
        things: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/things/"),
      },
```

This is because the craco.config.js json format is different then webpack format

Ref: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file

After that, I also updated your thing.js to

```
import React from "react"

const thing = () => { return <div> Stackover</div>}
export default thing;
```

Comment: you nailed! indeed resolve was unnecesary. I should take a in-deep look to CRACO configuration file to avoid more troubles like this